# Circular reference caused by alias in query definition error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to insert data into a third table from two other tables using a union query, but I am getting an error:

> Circular reference caused by alias in query definition error

```
Q1 = "Insert into Final_PQR (Onshore_Architect,Offshore,PQR_Number,Task,PQR_Type,Status,Latest_Update,Planned_Work,Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours) "
Q1 = Q1 & " Select Distinct V.Onshore_Architect,V.Offshore,V.PQR_Number,V.Task,V.PQR_Type,V.Status,V.Latest_Update,V.Planned_Work,V.Comments,V.Remaining_Planned_hours"
Q1 = Q1 & " from [Select distinct Onshore_Architect As Onshore_Architect,Offshore As Offshore,PQR_Number As PQR_Number,Task As Task,PQR_Type As PQR_Type,Status As Status,Latest_Update As Latest_Update,Planned_Work As Planned_Work,Comments As Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours As Remaining_Planned_hours from PQR_Deepika_Final"
Q1 = Q1 & " UNION Select distinct Onshore_Architect,Offshore,PQR_Number,Task,PQR_Type,Status,Latest_Update,Planned_Work,Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours from PQR_Sonal_Final"
Q1 = Q1 & "]. As V;"

CurrentDb.Execute Q1
```

Comment: I've never seen `from [select ... union select ...]. AS V` syntax.  Is that legal in Access.

Comment: Wow!  `from [select ... union select ...]. AS V` is valid (tested Access 2010).  Did not expect that.  Does the query run if you remove the insert statement?

Comment: Tim, Yes it works. and destination-data , Yup it is working when we remove that statement. I guess the issue was with alias that I was using. It is now resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error refers to these kinds of aliases: `Offshore As Offshore`, `Comments As Comments`.

You can't alias something to it's current name.

Remove these and it might run:

```
Q1 = "Insert into Final_PQR (Onshore_Architect,Offshore,PQR_Number,Task,PQR_Type,Status,Latest_Update,Planned_Work,Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours) "
Q1 = Q1 & " Select Distinct V.Onshore_Architect,V.Offshore,V.PQR_Number,V.Task,V.PQR_Type,V.Status,V.Latest_Update,V.Planned_Work,V.Comments,V.Remaining_Planned_hours"
Q1 = Q1 & " from [Select distinct Onshore_Architect,Offshore,PQR_Number,Task,PQR_Type,Status,Latest_Update,Planned_Work,Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours from PQR_Deepika_Final"
Q1 = Q1 & " UNION Select distinct Onshore_Architect,Offshore,PQR_Number,Task,PQR_Type,Status,Latest_Update,Planned_Work,Comments,Remaining_Planned_hours from PQR_Sonal_Final"
Q1 = Q1 & "]. As V;"

CurrentDb.Execute Q1
```

You should also consider using a more typical syntax for your subquery. The current syntax `FROM [subquery]. As Alias` is really odd. The usual syntax is `FROM (subquery) As Alias` Or `FROM (subquery) Alias`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding

select * from
(

) as tbl

to your query

insert into yourtable
select * from
(
select * from yourselecttable
) as tbl
order by fld